# R microbenching loop vs vector vs parallel is yielding inverted results

Tags: r, for-loop, parallel-processing, vectorization, microbenchmark

I'm having a weird issue and not able to identify the root[image] cause. I wrote a simple for-loop, vector, and parallel core and running in the Jupyter environment.

```
fn_loop <- function(x1, nrep = 1000) {
    n1 <- length(x1)
    B <- nrep

    Tboot <- rep(NA, B)
    xx1 <- rep(NA, n1)

    for (i in 1:B) {
        xx1 <- sample(x1, n1, replace = TRUE) # sample of size n1 with replacement from x1
        Tboot[i] <- mean(xx1) 
    }
    return(Tboot)
}

fn_vec <- function(x1, nrep = 1000) {
    n1 <- length(x1)
    B <- nrep


    Tboot <- lapply(1:nrep, function(i){ mean(sample(x1, n1, replace = TRUE))})
    return(Tboot)
}

fn_par  <- function(x1, nrep = 1000) {
    n1 <- length(x1)
    B <- nrep


    Tboot <- mclapply(1:nrep, function(i){ mean(sample(x1, n1, replace = TRUE))}, mc.cores=8)
    return(Tboot)
}

#Benchmark forloop, vector, parallel codes
library(microbenchmark)
m <- microbenchmark(times = 1000, # default is 100
  "loop"         = fn_loop(x1, 1000),                  
  "vector"       = fn_vec(x1, 1000),
  "parallel"     = fn_par(x1, 1000))

ggplot2::autoplot(m)
```

The results in the ggplot2 are inverted...loop is taking the least amount of code compared to parallel. Can someone please point my mistake. Thanks .

Comment: One thing to note, lapply is not vectorized, it is just a condensed version of a for loop.

Comment: Thanks Dave! This is helpful. What can be used for vectorization in the for-loop above?

Comment: Fastest would be to sample `n1*nrep`, put them in a matrix, and calculate `colMeans`.

Comment: Thank you, user2554330. With your hint, I was able to vectorize it and saw the gain in the performance. Do you have any hints how can I parallelize this sample on a cluster? I am reading on parLapply and parSapply. My challenge is I have two such vectors (x1, x2) that I want to sample from 1000 times and run the simulation for 10K times  and calculate the means of each simulation for x1 and x2 and return the ratio of the means. I think this is an example from t-Boostrappping.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind with parallel processing is there is a certain overhead associated with set-up: breaking the problem into parts, allocating to the different cores and reassembling the results. In this case sampling 1000 times is not time consuming enough that the parallel processing provides a benefit. Parallel processing will provide a benefit as the number of samples drawn increases to say over `sample(x1, 10000, replace = TRUE))`.